# How to get Woocommerce Product Categories within a Plugin File

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get all the Product Categories inside a Wordpress Plugin with the following Code. I have tried the same code within the active theme and they are working and gives the right output but when I am trying to do the same inside the plugin file it returns an empty array. Is there any other way to do this? wht `get_categories()` is not working inside the plugin file?

**EDIT: this I am using as the response to a AJAX call as below.**

My Code as follow,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tcf_et_mp_get_categories', 'tcf_et_mp_get_categories' );
function tcf_et_mp_get_categories(){

    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $orderby      = 'name';  
    $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
    $title        = '';  
    $empty        = 1;

    $args = array(  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                     'orderby'      => $orderby,
                     'show_count'   => $show_count,
                     'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                     'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                     'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty );

    $all_materials = get_categories( $args );

    foreach($all_materials as $material){
         $materials_drop_down .= '<option value="'.$material->term_id.'" '.$selected_str.'>'.$material->name.'</option>';
    }
    //print_r( $all_materials );
    wp_send_json( $materials_drop_down );
    die();
}
```

Comment: Inside which hook you are using this code ?

Comment: I do not use any hook for this. I need to return list of categories for an AJAX call.

Comment: if are getting error 'invalid_taxonomy'... it indicates that your register taxonomy is getting called after your ajax call.... Theck the function priorities....If you have added you taxonomy to 'init' action then it should work ... but it depends on what code you have done.... contextual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve this with MySQL Query here I m trying to get Woocommerce Product Categories in a WP AJAX function where `get_categories()` or `get_terms()` does not work for `product_cat` taxonomy. But within this function I can execute WP MySQL Quires so the following code produces and returns the expected output.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tcf_et_mp_get_categories', 'tcf_et_mp_get_categories' );
function tcf_et_mp_get_categories()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $categories = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT wp_terms.* 
                                        FROM wp_terms 
                                        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
                                        WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'" );

    $materials_drop_down = '<select>';
    $materials_drop_down .= '<option value="0">Choose Material Type</option>';
    foreach( $categories as $category )
    {
        $materials_drop_down .= '<option value="'. $category->term_id .'">' . $category->name . '</option>';
    }
    $materials_drop_down = '</select>';

    wp_send_json( $materials_drop_down );
    die;
}
```

Hope this will help for someone.

Answer (score 1):

The function `get_categories()` is used for Wordpress categories. Instead you should use `get_terms()` **for a "custom taxonomy" as Product categories**:

```
$all_materials = get_terms( array(  
    'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'show_count'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'   => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'title_li'     => '',
    'hide_empty'   => 1 
) );

// Test raw output
print_r( $all_materials );
```

Comment: This returns the following error `WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) ) ` but your code works in the theme template file.

Comment: @mapmalith So may be you will need to add some more related code in your question, as this way I will be able **to test** your issue and really try to give you a correct solution.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is AJAX. `wp_ajax_tcf_et_mp_get_categories` is the action call back for `add_action( 'wp_ajax_...`

Comment: It is not a action hook or anything but my own function for `wp_ajax_...`. [Reference link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Comment: @mapmalith Is exactly what I am saying… what is called a call back is just `tcf_et_mp_get_categories` and `wp_ajax_tcf_et_mp_get_categories` is the Ajax hook of this call back… But *"Questions seeking debugging help should include **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*** … You should understand that with your actual code i can't test anything…

Answer (score 0):

try to get `category_id` form `wp_wc_category_lookup` table.

```php
    global $wpdb;
    $cats = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT category_id from {$wpdb->prefix}wc_category_lookup");
```